# validate textbox but postback resets hidden field?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net button:

```
 <asp:Button ID="MainContent_ibSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />
                </td>
```

I need to keep the `runat=server` because I have to process some code behind when its clicked.
But in the jquery I have this:

```
 $("#MainContent_ibSave").click(function () {
            if ($('#MainContent_txtShipToName').val().length == 0) {
                $('#hErrorsExist').val("1");
                $('#error').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#hErrorsExist').val("0");
                $('#error').hide();
            }
```

Basically what I'm doing here is just checking if any text has been entered in #MainContent_txtShipToName.  I want to throw an error message if nothing is entered.  To do so I thought I'd add a hidden field:

```
<input id="hErrorsExist" type="hidden" />
```

To maintain the state of whether an error exists on the page or not.
This is so if an error exists on the form I can set the value to 1 otherwise I set it to 0.

After I click this button it sets the value to 1 shows the #error (which is just a div), but then the div disappears.  Its as if the postback has reset the value of hErrorsExist...

I even added a check in my jquery:

```
  if ($('#hErrorsExist').val() == "0" || $('#hErrorsExist').val().length == 0) {
            alert("about to hide");
            $('#error').hide();
            alert($('#hErrorsExist').val());
        }
        else {
            $('#error').show();
            alert($('#hErrorsExist').val());
        }
```

This is the first thing in my document ready function.  I dont know how to handle this so that the div #error stays up even after the button post back.  If I do enter a value and it validates it should set hErrorsExist to 0 and hide the div #error and keep the div hidden after post back.

**Here's the full jquery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        /*hide message container on top*/
        //alert($('#hErrorsExist').val().length);
        if ($('#hErrorsExist').val() == "0" || $('#hErrorsExist').val().length == 0) {
            alert("about to hide");
            $('#error').hide();
            alert($('#hErrorsExist').val());
        }
        else {
            $('#error').show();
            alert($('#hErrorsExist').val());
        }

          $("#MainContent_ibSave").click(function () {
            if ($('#MainContent_txtShipToName').val().length == 0) {
                $('#hErrorsExist').val("1");
                alert("Setting to 1");
                alert($('#hErrorsExist').val());
                $('#error').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#hErrorsExist').val("0");
                alert("Setting to 0");
                alert($('#hErrorsExist').val());
                $('#error').hide();
            }
        });
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$("#<%= MainContent_ibSave.ClientID %>").click(function (arg) {
   arg.preventDefault();
   if ($('#MainContent_txtShipToName').val().length == 0) {
       $('#hErrorsExist').val("1");
       $('#error').show();
   }
   else {
       $('#hErrorsExist').val("0");
       $('#error').hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: Does the same thing ... I click the "save" button, and it sets the value to 1, dispalys the error message but then disappears again...This is the problem I am having.

Comment: I think it has to do with the beginning of my jquery code see my post at the end where I list all my jquery.  It looks like this hidden field is empty after the post back...

Comment: updated :), the problem is that the asp button when render it transform to a submit button and every time you click on it, the page re-send to the server and cause a postback. so you can use the .preventDefault() to avoid the postback.